# How to pass DetailView over the 'slug' in url?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-urls, django-class-based-views, django-1.4

How to pass [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView) over the 'slug' in url?

First, let's look at my code.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^customer/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$', customerDetailView.as_view()),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class customerDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'customerDetail'
    template_name = "customerDetail.html"
    allow_empty = True
    model = Customer
    slug_field = 'name' # 'name' is field of Customer Model
```

Now, my code is like above.

And I want to change code like below.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^customer/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$', customer),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class customerDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'customerDetail'
    template_name = "customerDetail.html"
    allow_empty = True
    model = Customer
    slug_field = 'name' # 'name' is field of Customer Model

def customer(request, slug):
    if request.method == "DELETE":
        pass # some code blah blah
    elif request.method == "POST"
        pass
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return customerDetailView.as_view(slug=slug)(request) # But this line is not working... just causing error TypeError, customerDetailView() received an invalid keyword 'slug'
```

As you know, DetailView need to 'slug' or 'pk'... So I must deliver 'slug' over to the DetailView... But I don't know how do I deliver 'slug'...

I'm waiting your answer front of moniter...

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way should be

```
return customerDetailView.as_view()(request, slug=slug)
```